# Android - LocationManager.addProximityAlert() method

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am writing and app that uses GPS to count the laps while the users runs into a circuit. I need my location listening to be very accurate so that I won't increment laps number wrongly.

Is there a way to set, or at least to know the default accuracy of the method `addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)` declared in `LocationManager` ? For accuracy I mean the accuracy of the Location that will be listened.

(In my case: in an application for runners I need to be very very accurate: I wanted the locations listened to have an accuracy of max 20/30 m and to set a radius of the center location at 10m).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of the GPS location depends (mainly) on the hardware, not the software.

For this reason, you can not **set** the accuracy given by this method.

What you can do is **get** this accuracy of the device by using the [getAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29) method from the `Location` object.

Comment: Maybe I explained wrong, For setting an accuracy I meant set a maxAccuracy and if a location listened has an accuracy > maxAccuracy, no eventi is triggered. Unfortunately I am not able to get any Location object if I use the addProximityAlert method